# How is it possible for an iframe to access its parents DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

How is it possible for a script within an `<iframe>` to have any notion of the page containing it? Can a script in the frame access any context outside of it? What about cross-domain?

Up until now I believed an `<iframe>` is *completely* agnostic to the containing page, but I have seen an example which contradicts this belief.

What exactly can and can't be done from within an `<iframe>` with respect to the containing page?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If the content of the iframe and its parent have the same domain, you can access the parent pages DOM from the iframe by using `parent.document.getElement...`.

However you can't do this cross-domain (not even across different subdomains) as it will result in:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Comment: just for reference, `top` is the top document, `self` is the current document and `parent` is the document above the current one.

Comment: Learn something new every day :)

Comment: @oezi, I have a document that loads iframe from a different domain. I was able to manipulate the iframe attributes from within the document loaded in that iframe. I used parent.document.getElementById() to get the element and then add an attribute using $(ele).attr('width','100%');

I have no clue why it worked for me. Let me know if you want to know any specifics of my environment to have better idea of this problem. Thanks

Comment: @Rishabh which browser did you use?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you can't communicate between the two DOMs across domains. However, there is a way to pass messages between the two using the hash portion of the iframe's url. For iframes on the same domain, see [oezi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620755/2620789#2620789).

[This might be of some help](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes), and there's plenty of other questions on the topic around here.

Comment: interesting article, strange that it dismisses html5's postmessage as having not enough support yet as safari, chrome, firefox, opera and even MSIE8 support it. with the jquery postmessage plugin (which uses some of the techniques used in the article you link) it becomes entirely cross-browser.

Comment: I think that's understandable - it was written in March 2008 :) That jQuery plugin sounds very interesting though.

Answer (score 2):

If they aren't on the same domain, you can communicate some information through the url fragment/hash. Here is a good example of that process...

http://www.tagneto.org/blogcode/xframe/ui.html