# target the body outside of an iframe

Tags: jquery

I need to change the style of the  tag, but i will be inside of an iframe and only want to change the main  tag not the one inside the iframe.

What is the best way to target the highest level body tag on a page with Jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate with excellent explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604839/accessing-an-element-outside-of-iframe,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) will travel multilevels until it finds the given filter, or reaches the top-most element.

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate matters with jquery? You can refer to the main body with `document.body`.