# is it possible that iframe resize itself without help from main window?

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize, no-framework

Both main window and iframe are on the same domain, but what I want to achieve is to resize iframe to fit its contents using js only within that iframe.

I also do not know the id of the iframe that is assigned to it by main window. And I do not want to use jquery or any other framework for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this also without knowing the `id`of the `iframe` in the parent window:

```
window.frameElement.style.width = iframeContentWidth + 'px';
window.frameElement.style.height = iframeContentHeight + 'px';
```

See `frameElement` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.frameElement).

**EDIT**

Just in case the `iframe` happens to be in a container element which has fixed size and `overflow: hidden` you can do something like this:

```
function resizeIframe (iframeContentWidth, iframeContentHeight) {
    var container = window.frameElement.parentElement;
    if (container != parent.document.body) {
        container.style.width = iframeContentWidth + 'px';
        container.style.height = iframeContentHeight + 'px';
    }
    window.frameElement.style.width = iframeContentWidth + 'px';
    window.frameElement.style.height = iframeContentHeight + 'px';
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For same-origin content like yours, [yes you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604839/accessing-an-element-outside-of-iframe).

To borrow from Gary's answer on the above question:

> In the iframe, window.parent refers to the global object of the parent
>   document, not the document object itself. I believe you would need to
>   use parent.document.getElementById

Try accessing the iframe using parent.document, and see if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only 1 IFRAME in the main window, from the Javascript of the IFRAME's document you can do something like:

```
function getMySelf()
{
    return (window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"))[0];
}

var myself = getMySelf();
myself.style.width = whateverWidth;
myself.style.height = whateverHeight;
```