# Firefox: Resize iframe according to actual content

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I have an iframe and I am trying to resize it based on its actual content (like so I dont get any scrolling). I have tried the following:

> alert(document.getElementById(iframe).contentWindow.document.body.height);
>                       alert(document.getElementById(iframe).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight);
>                       alert(document.getElementById(iframe).contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight);

None of those work. iframe contains the id of the iframe. The last two lines work in Chrome.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are both documents on the same domain?

Comment: Duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806947/is-it-possible-that-iframe-resize-itself-without-help-from-main-window

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot access the properties of the document in the iframe from the outside document, but you can do it the other way: access the properties of the document in the iframe from within that document itself, and then call a function in the outside document. This outside function would then do the resizing, as described here: [Resize iframe height according to content height in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526373/246622)