# Javascript: How can I get ancestor element of a dynamically written iframe from within the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a div on a page that is used by Google to write out a child div and child iframe ad inside of it.

```
<div id="ads-pos-111" class="module ad ad-111" data-pos="922"></div>
```

When the iframe ad is written, the DOM looks like this:

```
<div id="ads-pos-111" class="module ad ad-111" data-pos="922">
    <div id="google_ads_iframe_/123456/consumer/hco_3__container__" style="border: 0pt none;">
         <iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/123456/consumer/hco_3" title="3rd party ad content" name="google_ads_iframe_/123456/consumer/hco_3" width="1" height="8" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" srcdoc="" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%; height: 578px; margin: 0px;"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to write Javascript code inside the iframe that can traverse its ancestors to get the value of the `data-pos` attribute two ancestors above. I would like to use something like `jQuery.closest('.data-pos')`.

I cannot use the iframe name as an anchor point as the name is generated dynamically by Google. Nor can I use the parent div ID, as there are potentially multiple ads on the page. So,I can't use code like `window.parent.$('#google_ads_iframe_/123456/consumer/hco_3')` as I won't know the *ID*.  Each iframe needs to "self-detect" what `"data-pos"` it is located in.

Has anybody encountered this situation?
(iframes are served on same domain as parent page)

Comment: If there are no cross-domain issues, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806947/is-it-possible-that-iframe-resize-itself-without-help-from-main-window/11807287#11807287 .

Comment: Is there only going to be one iframe on the page? If so, just use $('iframe').parent().parent().attr('data-pos') to get what you're looking for once it renders. Here's a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hafutekacu/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @yoursweater: There are many iframes on the page as Google is serving a bunch of ads.  So, your syntax cannot help me.  Teemu's answer seems to be what I am looking for.

Comment: @Teemu: Thanks for the link.  I did not know window.frameElement existed.  Just tested it and I was able to get the value.