# how to manipulate elements outside of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to manipulate elements outside of iframe by setting JS inside of my iframe
The style.backgroundColor code works but not innerHtml

I have

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
           //get main document element.
           var ititle= parent.document.getElementById('MainTitle');
           //works          
           ititle.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCC00";
       //doesn't work
       ititle.innerHtml='test html';
</script>
```

The above script is inside my iframe

Are there any reasons why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It shouldn't be `innerHTML` ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML

Comment: Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604839/accessing-an-element-outside-of-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing an element outside of iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604839/accessing-an-element-outside-of-iframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because JavaScript is CaseSensitive, and it's `innerHTML` (all uppers):

```
 ititle.innerHtml='test html';
 //should be
 ititle.innerHTML='test html';
```

Comment: ok. that was dumb. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, we've all been there. I've asked a huuuuge question here once, only to see the syntax highlighting applied just after I posted it, and realize that I had forgotten an apostrophe somewhere :)