# modifying css for a frame element

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint

I have a page which can be opened as a pop up page in sharepoint .Now when the page is opened as pop up I want some css to be modified.What is happening is that the code is able to successfully modify the label element but unable to modify the .ms-dlgTitleText which is the window sharepoint opens which holds the page and is above the iFrame element holding the page.Can someone please tell me what I can do here.

EDIT:I want to know how I can change the content inside the div with the class ms-dlgTitle

```
<div class="dialogue>
<div class="ms-dlgTitle">
content
</div>
<div class="dlgframe">

<iframe>
some data

    <script src="/_layouts/1033/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function () 
     {if (window.location.search.match("[?&]IsDlg=1")) 
        {
            alert("doc is ready now"); 
            $('<style type="text/css">.ms-dlgTitle{ width: 200px; } #foo{background:black;                     }</style>').appendTo("head");}});

     function t(){  var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();options.url =           "http://sharepointhost:2266";options.height =      300;SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                 }
     </script>
    <a class="s" onclick="javascript:t()">k</a> <label title="label1" id="foo">lbl</label>
</iFrame>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might need to elaborate a little more on your problem description. It's not entirely clear to me what the context is. What is a pop up page in sharepoint, or do you mean a pop-up in the browser. Are you trying to alter the styling for the content presented in the iframe?

Comment: So what happens is this page opens in a modal dialogue in sharepoint or say we have a regular page and then a modal dialogue is opened ..I am trying to alter the content outside the iFrame and I have the code inside the page which loads in the iFrame

Comment: Changed the code and added div's for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog options you can pass arguments to the dialog. Example of this can be found [here](http://www.sharepointdevelopment.me/2011/06/passing-data-to-and-from-sharepoint-modal-dialogs/).

On the page load itself I would check if the argument is available and then change your page css with for ex. the help of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for replying..I don't want any arguments..What I want is that I want to modify the modal box which holds the iFrame..since my page loads inside the iFrame whatever style I add to the style element does not affect the box or the div which sits above the iFrame which has the page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you want to do is modify the "parent" page with scripts within the iframe. This isn't possible unless both pages come from the same host, the same port, and use the same protocol. If that's the case you can use `parent.document.getElementById()` or, perhaps more convenient in your situation, `parent.document.getElementsByClassName()`.

If that's not the case (if your pages come from diferent hosts, ports or under different protocols), you'd have to use `window.postMessage` to communicate between your iframe and your parent document.

A very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604839/accessing-an-element-outside-of-iframe) had already answered. I suggest you give it a look.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for ..can you please tell me how do I  apply this code to access the parent elemnt and change it.This is the jQuery function i use to access the .ms-dlgTitle which is outside the iFrame  $('<style type="text/css">.ms-dlgTitle{ width: 200px; } #foo{background:black;                     }</style>').appendTo("head");}});

Comment: $('.ms-dlgTitle').addClass('nameOfClassToAdd') or if you want to set the css directly without using classes, which I don't recommend, $('.ms-dlgTitle').css('attribute', 'value')

Comment: I am using this in the page to modify the parent container as suggested in the article var tt= window.parent.document.getElementById("dialogTitleSpan");
tt.style.width = "123px";
 but this does not seem to be doing anything

Comment: Is the console displaying anything? Check your web inspector for any console messages that might give you a clue on any error that might be occurring.

Comment: I am using this $("#ms-dlgContent",parent.document).css("color", "orange")
 and it seems to be working good.Thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: jQuery to the rescue! hahah No problem man. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct, btw. :)