# How to set the data to the variable of parent window of offline html file from iframe of localhost?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In my html page(file:///C:/Users/NEC/Desktop/test.html) has the javascript variable(or input text field) and `iframe` that call to other host(localhost:8081/TProject/sample.html).

In test.html

```
<iframe src="localhost:8081/TProject/sample.html" ></iframe><br/>
<input type="text" id="output" ><br />
```

And, in my sample.html shown in `iframe` has follow `javascript` code to change the value of input text of parent window.

```
function setData() {
  window.parent.getElementById("output").value = "hello"; 
}
```

Error message is:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "localhost:8081" from 
accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of 
"http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.
```

How can I pass the value (javascript variable) to offline html page from online server?

Comment: use postMessage() to talk between frames on different protocols.

Comment: Similar article at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604839/accessing-an-element-outside-of-iframe

Comment: my parent page is offline. so i can't send message to parent error message of using postMessage() isFailed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:8081') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your answers.
Now I can solve my problem by using "window.parent.postMessage()".

from local host server page of iframe use following to send message

```
window.parent.postMessage({ message: 'successfully connected'}, "*");
```

and from offline page catch that message with

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  document.getElementById("output").value = event.data.message;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http:80//TProject/sample.html" ></iframe>

<iframe src="your_path_in_your_hard_drive/TProject/sample.html" ></iframe>
```

I think you cannot use localhost in the src attribute, try any one of the above link in src attribute.