# Is it possible to set location href/src of an iframe without knowing it's id?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe that I run code inside. I don't know the iframes ID as it's set by another application. I wish to change the page in the iframe to another url. How can I do this without knowing the id?

sample html:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kE9WdSTWe4GdDKPbFboV?p=catalogue

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` should do

Comment: the method commented by phylax is only aplicable if you have a single iframe only, can you put your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: what code? I', running a facebook-tab-app, I could select the iframe in some various ways, but it's hard to be sure it won't change, thus breaking the app.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren It would be good to share your rendered HTML, can you share ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the URL that you want to replace you can do this :

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (var i = frames.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(frames[i].src == "currentURL"){
     frames[i].src = "newURL"
  }
}
```

Or If you are the page inside the iframe you can simply redirect the page :

```
window.location.replace("http://www.newlocation.com")
```

Comment: But when I think about it, will this really work to run inside the iframe, does my iframe know what's outside it, including itself?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren what exactly is the context of the script? are you trying to put this script in a page that will be called by an iframe and then you want to change the source of the iframe? or will this be in your page that contains the iframe?

Comment: the first, inside a page that will be called by an iframe.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren let me know if this works, but I don't think it will. I'm going to look into it, but I think it can be done.

Comment: For some reason my array isn't looping. I do get an array of frames0: iframe#fb_xdm_frame_https
1: iframe
2: iframe#vimeo
3: iframe
4: iframe
5: iframe
f2df062044: iframe
f3cc14cccc: iframe
f266b0cb9c: iframe
fb_xdm_frame_https: iframe#fb_xdm_frame_https
fbd403e2c: iframe

Comment: @KristofferNolgren it is looping, but it's getting the iframes from the page with the loop. I don't know what that is you posted

Comment: @KristofferNolgren after some digging, the only way what you want to do is possible, is if both the iFrame and the parent document come from the same host. More info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604839/accessing-an-element-outside-of-iframe

Comment: one solution I have concidered that is dirty is to fake a click on a link inside the dom of the iframe.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren you don't even need to do that actually... here is what you can do : `window.location.replace("http://www.newlocation.com")`

Comment: great, if you write an answer with that solution i'll give you the credit!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single iframe, do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = "url"
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns `NodeList`, on which you can use index to use the specific element from the list.

Index start at 0

Comment: Nice, i don't though, I have facebook-buttons and vime-windows aswell.