# CodeMirror: Javascript in iframe not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, codemirror

I am trying to built code player that shows result of html page including script in iframe. but something seems to be wrong here. it seems javascript not working every time i click button i see error in console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror/theme/solarized.css">

          <script src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
          <script src="codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
          <script src="codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>

    </head> <style> .CodeMirror{border:1px solid black} </style>
     <body>
            <form>
         <div id="editorContainer" style="width:50%">
           <textarea id="code" name="code" class="CodeMirror">

          <button id="btn" onclick="say()">hello</button>
            <script>

                function say(){
                   alert('test')
                 }
         </script>



           </textarea>
         </div>
         </form>
         <button>click</button>
         <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                mode: "text/html",
                lineNumbers: true
              });
              $("button").click(function(){

                  var code= editor.getValue();
                  $("iframe").contents().find("html").html(code);
              })
      </script>

  </body>
  </html
```

>

Comment: what is the error in console can you please add that?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604839/accessing-an-element-outside-of-iframe

Comment: VM213 about:blank:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: say is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM213 about:blank:1)