# Pass values into iframe not using GET

Tags: javascript, html, post, get

I have an iframe that I was formally creating using a url with some vars that I was passing in as a GET. Is it possible to set the source page and pass in the variables as a POST or something? Or really, if it's possible to somehow get at the variables stored in the parent I'd be fine with that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `window.parent` from within the iframe.

In the parent window:

```
window.passingObj = { "key" : "value" };
```

In the iframe:

```
alert(window.parent.passingObj["key"]); // value
```

Answer (score 1):

Two helpful posts:

[iframe accessing parent DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620755/iframe-accessing-parent-dom) (iframe to parent)

[Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page) (parent to iframe)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need access in javascript then you can use the `hash`.

```
iframe.src="http://foo.bar/#arg1=1&arg2=2";
```

and then in the page you just extract them from `location.hash.substring(1)`.

this is boilerplate code for getting these args into a 'map':
(from my library easyXDM)

```
var query = (function(input){
    input = input.substring(1).split("&");
    var data = {}, pair, i = input.length;
    while (i--) {
        pair = input[i].split("=");
        data[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return data;
}(location.hash);

query.arg1; // 1
query.arg2; // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If both pages are in the same domain, you can access variables defined in the container page from the iframe using

```
parent.varName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables and method from the parent window of the iframe simply using the **parent** object; for instance, if you have this in the parent window:

```
var someObject = {key1:'value1' , key2:'value2'};
function test(key)
{
    alert(someObject[key]);
}
```

you can do this in the child iframe:

```
parent.test('key1');
alert(parent.someObject.key2);
```

Keep in mind it is only possible if the iframe and its parent belong to the same domain
(Same Origin Policy).

Answer (score 0):

For what you're saying I gather that you don't want to use the url to pass your parameter.

Depending on where the javascript is executed you have these options:

- If executed in the container window you would do something like this

  ```
  ...
  var el = document.getElementById('targetFrameId');

  getIframeWindow(el).someFunction('value1', 'value2', ...);
  // or
  getIframeWindow(el).someVariable = {key1:'value1', key2:'value2', ...};
  ...
  ```
- If executed in the iframe window you would do something like this

  ```
  ... window.parent.something ... ;
  ```

Annexe

```
function getIframeWindow(iframe_object) {
  var doc;

  if (iframe_object.contentWindow) {
    return iframe_object.contentWindow;
  }

  if (iframe_object.window) {
    return iframe_object.window;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.contentDocument) {
    doc = iframe_object.contentDocument;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.document) {
    doc = iframe_object.document;
  }

  if (doc && doc.defaultView) {
   return doc.defaultView;
  }

  if (doc && doc.parentWindow) {
    return doc.parentWindow;
  }

  return undefined;
}
```