# gwt - access from iframe page

Tags: html, gwt, dom, iframe

mainpage.html

```
<html>
<div id="123" name="foo"></div>
<iframe src="/innerpage.html"></iframe>
</html>
```

innerpage.html:

```
<html> 
 and here is some GWT widget that needs to access the div with id="123":
 DOM.getElementById("123").getAttribute("name") 
</html>
```

#### Is it possible to access the div on mainpage within the inner page?

Comment: Just as an FYI -- you don't have to deploy gwt as an iframe...

Comment: That is also a good point, if you can, I would deploy GWT directly into the page as it removes other headaches as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jsni you can do this:

[iframe accessing parent DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620755/iframe-accessing-parent-dom)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using parent.getElementById("123");

Note that the innerpage and mainpage will likely need to be within the same domain to prevent this getting flagged as cross-site scripting.