# iframe loading time limit use javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, settimeout

i need to stop loading my iframe page after 5000 ms i'm use these but it's refresh the iframe every 5000 ms later what the problem . pleas fix it pleas. thanks

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="" width="920" height="900" border="2"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setIframeSrc() {
  var s = "http://lx5.in/CGIT-Results-p2-2013.php";
  var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iframe1');
  if ( -1 == navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") ) {
    iframe1.src = s;
setTimeout(setIframeSrc, 5000);
  }
  else {
    iframe1.location = s;
setTimeout(setIframeSrc, 5000);
  }
}
setTimeout(setIframeSrc, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you `set` the iframe src instead of removing it when you want to *stop* it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop iframe loading you can use the following code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943219/how-to-stop-page-load-in-html-static-page#10415265):

```
function setIframeSrc() {
  var s = "http://lx5.in/CGIT-Results-p2-2013.php";
  var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iframe1');
  iframe1.src = s;
  setTimeout(function(){
      if (window.stop) {
          window.stop();
      } else {
          document.execCommand('Stop'); // MSIE
      }
  }, 5000);
}
setTimeout(setIframeSrc, 5000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tsmqn/7/) / [jsfiddle/show](http://jsfiddle.net/Tsmqn/7/show)

Comment: if i need to stop many iframe with a same id .each iframe i need stop 1000 how to set it ?

Comment: <iframe id="iframe1" src=".." ...> = 20s load
<iframe id="iframe1" src=".." ...> = 20s load
<iframe id="iframe1" src=".." ...> = 20s load
<iframe id="iframe1" src=".." ...> = 20s load
for these four iframe i need each stop after 20s .
pleas help me how to stop it

Comment: Improved version http://jsfiddle.net/qvhu6wh6/3/ - cancel timeout if page in iframe was successfully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rethinking the idea. IMO it should be the server that displays timeout information and not the client using some JavaScript timeouts. Explanation below.

Your code just says: refresh the iframe every 5 seconds.

You cannot stop iframe request execution. You can change iframe's src location or remove it from the DOM tree. But the request that is started is unstoppable once it reaches the server.

So:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="{url to query}" ...>
```

and in the script:

```
function displayTimeout() {
 (...)
 var p = iframe1.parentNode;
 p.removeChild(iframe1);
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 var text = document.createTextNode("Timeout loading iframe");
 div.appendChild(text);
 p.appendChild(div);
}
setTimeout(displayTimeout,5000);
```

But this solution **has serious drawbacks** - in order not to display timeout when iframe manages to load in time you should cancel the timeout. But how to do that?

If you want to do it from iframe - see [iframe accessing parent DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620755/iframe-accessing-parent-dom)

If from parent element - see [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

The further you go, the more problems and the more complicated the solution becomes. So I would suggest abandoning it.