# IFRAME - If loading time > 100ms delete this iframe and load with diffrent content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to create html page with interesting feature. Page load IFRAME with image lets say image1.jpg, but if loading this image take more then 100ms i want to load iframe with image2.jpg.

I tried to do it all day, is it possible?

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="frameid" width="310" height="255" src="image1.jpg"></iframe>
<script language="javascript">

iframe = document.getElementById("frameid");

var t0 = new Date();
var t00 = t0.getMilliseconds();  
 WaitForIFrame();
var t1 = new Date();
var t11 = t1.getMilliseconds(); 

var t2 = t11-t00;
if(t2 > 100) { remove()}

function WaitForIFrame() {
    if (iframe.readyState != "complete") {  

    setTimeout(function() {window.frames[0].stop();},60);
                                         }
    else { 
            done();
         }
                        }
 function done() {
    //some code after iframe has been loaded if you want

                }

  function remove(){

  var frame = document.getElementById("frameid");
  frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
              }    
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to compare two times and then remove one iframe, but its sth wrong with this idea

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759103/iframe-loading-time-limit-use-javascript