# Find hosting tag of iFrame from within the iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="container">
   <h1> here is the iframe </h1>
   <iframe src="...."></iframe>
</div>
```

I need to be able to get the id of the div that the iframe is in (id="container") from within the iFrame. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620755/how-is-it-possible-for-an-iframe-to-access-its-parents-dom).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see anything there that can be useful in my case.

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer, as explained in the answer on that question, is that if they are same origin, you should be able to access the `parent` property and go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

what I did at the end is to make the frame id, a function of its container id.
for instance:

```
<div id="container1">
    <iframe id="container1_iframe" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

then, from within the iFrame I got the iframe id like this: window.frameElement.id

and from its value I deducted the container id.

Comment: Should not need the detour via the ID, if you can access the iframe element via `window.frameElement`, then you should also be able to access its parent directly via `window.frameElement.parentNode`